# Perk Point maximum

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I was aware that there was a Street Cred cap. Is there a perk point cap? You get additional perk points by leveling individual skills, but the skill cap is linked to attributes. So if I went with Intelligence and Tech Ability that only have two linked skills and give less perk points (6) through leveling did I give myself a lower perk point cap? Body and Reflexes have three linked skills that give more perk points (7) each so it seems some builds would get significantly more perks. Is my math off or is there additional perks I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of perk points available depends entirely on your build - this is because as you have mentioned, each of the individual perk trees level individually based on the attribute points you allocate and the perk trees themselves will unlock additional perk points as they level. Therefore, if you do not put any points into Cool you will get very little Cold Blooded experience and any experience you do gain will be capped at the current level of Cool, therefore potentially missing out on the additional perk points you can get from the Cold Blooded perk tree.

It is not possible to complete every perk tree with the number of perk points in the game, but there are enough perk points available to provide flexibility in creating your build.

Not all perk trees are created equally. Body > Athletics for example will give you a free perk point at levels 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 16 and 19 while Technical > Crafting will give you a free perk point at levels 2, 5, 8, 10, 14, and 17. This means that yes, depending on your build choices you will have less perk points available. Maximising point allocation in the Intelligence, Technical or Cool trees would limit your maximum number of perk points by reducing the number of perk trees you can gain experience for (and thus unlock further perk points). It also means that the Body and Reflexes trees have more perk points available by investing in them, as they each unlock three perk trees which each give 6-7 perk points, rather than unlocking two perk trees which each give 6-7 perk points like Cool, Technical and Intelligence do.

Comment: Tyvm, I suspected it was the case but wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Some of the NCPD scanner sites reward Perk Shards as well -- these give a perk no strings attached.